# EditSensorComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem when I get to the edit route. I get this message -

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

When I comment input name error comeback for the next input. Looking my code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SensorService } from '../servicesapi/sensor.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ISensor } from '../sensor/sensor'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-sensor',
  templateUrl: './edit-sensor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-sensor.component.scss']
})
export class EditSensorComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  sens: ISensor;
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, 
 private 
  sensor: SensorService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  // this.sens = new ISensor();

  this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  this.sensor.getSingleSensor(this.id)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("data" , data)
      this.sens = data;
    }, error => console.log(error));
  }


  updateEmployee() {
    this.sensor.updateSensor(this.id, this.sens)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    // this.employee = new Employee();
    // this.gotoList();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.updateEmployee();
 }
}
```

Also my html showing error:

```
 <h3>Update Employee</h3>
 <div [hidden]="submitted" style="width: 400px;">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required 
  [(ngModel)]="sens.name" name="name"> //here is problem
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="path">Path</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="path" required 
 [(ngModel)]="sens.path" name="path">
    </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
 </div>
```

I can read the data. I can even startle them, but this error returns me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because the *EditSensorComponent's* HTML file is rendered by the DOM before the ngOnInit(). Now, since you've only defined *sens* and not initialized it, you're getting an undefined error

Try this:
1. Initialize the sens object in the *EditSensorComponent* while you're defining it.
2. Looking at the code, I'm assuming the **sens** object has two properties (name and path)

```
sens: ISensor = {
    name: '',
    path: ''
}
```